# Performance differences between '.find' and '.where' methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to know, regarding performance matters, what are differences between the `User.find(<id>)` method and the `User.where(:id => <id>)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `find` does more or less what you're describing with your `where`. You can find the details in [this post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/11/20/under-the-hood-activerecord-base-find-part-2). That being said, if you're looking to grab a single record by id, then you might want to use `find_one`. That's what `find` winds up doing when you call it with a single argument of an id, but you'll skip past all the other code it needs to run to figure out that's what you wanted.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, but: It really doesn't matter (unless you don't have a unique-constraint on your `id` column).

Comment: +1 You may want to elaborate, this is because find always returns a single record. Where returns all matched records unless a limit is supplied.

Comment: So, if I have a unique-constraint on my 'id' colum what is the best "performant" way?

Comment: It doesn't matter. `.find` wouldn't need to allocate an array (but that is an implementation detail you shouldn't care about). The reason to use `.find` is: `.find(foo)` is much more readable than `.where(:id => foo).first`.